# Android - move an ImageView on screen (Like dragging)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create an app that can move an `ImageView` on your device like dragging and when I put like 75% of the `ImageView` out of the screen show a `Toast` for example. I've been reading about `MotionEvent` and `onTouchListener` and I've followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview), but it doesn't convince me.

### Edit

My current code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    int windowwidth;
    int windowheight;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewGroup mRrootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        windowwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        windowheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
        mImageView = (ImageView) mRrootLayout.findViewById(R.id.im_move_zoom_rotate);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        if(X == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "OUT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (Y == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "OUT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        mRrootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I did those `if` and `else if` just to know if the `ImageView` is getting out of the device, on the left and right side of the device seems like it's okay, but I'd like to make it cleaner and not hardwritted, also I don't get the `LayoutParams(150,150)` why 150? Also I don't get why I have to create a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and why I have to put

```
layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
```

I did the `if/else if` because I want to delete when the user want to put the `ImageView` out of the device, so I need to control when he tries to, at the moment I only got it TOP/LEFT/RIGHT not down, I also get the dimensions of my device just to try if X or Y is the same as height or widht just show the `Toast` but it's not doing it correctly.

Now my `ImageView` is the `ic_launcher` but it will be bigger (almost middle screen).

### NOTE

If you know any other way to do that easier or cleanest, feel free to put it here, I don't care about my code, I can adapt it, I just want it to be clear and not hardcoded.

Comment: I came across a similar problem and then got a solution.
[Checking Drag Out of Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015840/dragging-button-is-going-out-of-the-screen)

Comment: If you know how to solve it (IF TESTED) feel free to put an answer and I'll test it out :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your routine works for the most part. In the following code, I have commented out sections that are not needed and made notations for those parts that need some explanation. Here is what the finished product looks like:

[image]

This graphic explains how the left margin is calculated. The same type of calculation applies to the top margin.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    int windowwidth; // Actually the width of the RelativeLayout.
    int windowheight; // Actually the height of the RelativeLayout.
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewGroup mRrootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // We are interested when the image view leaves its parent RelativeLayout
        // container and not the screen, so the following code is not needed.
//        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
//        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
//        windowwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
//        windowheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
        mImageView = (ImageView) mRrootLayout.findViewById(R.id.im_move_zoom_rotate);

        // These these following 2 lines that address layoutparams set the width
        // and height of the ImageView to 150 pixels and, as a side effect, clear any
        // params that will interfere with movement of the ImageView.
        // We will rely on the XML to define the size and avoid anything that will
        // interfere, so we will comment these lines out. (You can test out how a layout parameter
        // can interfere by setting android:layout_centerInParent="true" in the ImageView.
//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
//        mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // Capture the width of the RelativeLayout once it is laid out.
        mRrootLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                windowwidth = mRrootLayout.getWidth();
                windowheight = mRrootLayout.getHeight();
            }
        });
    }

    // Tracks when we have reported that the image view is out of bounds so we
    // don't over report.
    private boolean isOutReported = false;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        // Check if the image view is out of the parent view and report it if it is.
        // Only report once the image goes out and don't stack toasts.
        if (isOut(view)) {
            if (!isOutReported) {
                isOutReported = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "OUT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            isOutReported = false;
        }
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // _xDelta and _yDelta record how far inside the view we have touched. These
                // values are used to compute new margins when the view is moved.
                _xDelta = X - view.getLeft();
                _yDelta = Y - view.getTop();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // Do nothing
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
                // Image is centered to start, but we need to unhitch it to move it around.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                } else {
                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0);
                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
                }
                lp.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                lp.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                // Negative margins here ensure that we can move off the screen to the right
                // and on the bottom. Comment these lines out and you will see that
                // the image will be hemmed in on the right and bottom and will actually shrink.
                lp.rightMargin = view.getWidth() - lp.leftMargin - windowwidth;
                lp.bottomMargin = view.getHeight() - lp.topMargin - windowheight;
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                break;
        }
        // invalidate is redundant if layout params are set or not needed if they are not set.
//        mRrootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isOut(View view) {
        // Check to see if the view is out of bounds by calculating how many pixels
        // of the view must be out of bounds to and checking that at least that many
        // pixels are out.
        float percentageOut = 0.50f;
        int viewPctWidth = (int) (view.getWidth() * percentageOut);
        int viewPctHeight = (int) (view.getHeight() * percentageOut);

        return ((-view.getLeft() >= viewPctWidth) ||
            (view.getRight() - windowwidth) > viewPctWidth ||
            (-view.getTop() >= viewPctHeight) ||
            (view.getBottom() - windowheight) > viewPctHeight);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im_move_zoom_rotate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: nice answers and well explained, I did it with my ic_launcher and it's not working at 100% it says OUT when is going out by TOP/BOTTOM but left/right it's not working 100%, it's necessary to put layout_widht 150dp? couldn't be wrap_content? my image will be almost the same size of the screen, but now I'm testing it with ic_launcher....

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS That is curious. It works OK for me, but our environments must differ. Can you post the relevant XML layout that you are using and a description of your ic_launcher? Is it just a standard ic_launcher icon? I am wondering if your image isn't larger than it appears. btw, I updated how the negative margins are set in the code. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, see my [`XML LAYOUT`](https://paste.ofcode.org/8Pbh3kARdeFTFiE55EQAep), now it doesn't move because I put it on the middle of the screen... (I want it on the middle of the screen though), and I put 250sp but I'd like to put it bigger....

Comment: Look @Cheticamp, I'm using this [image](http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/shapes/circle.jpg) now, as I'm seeing 75% is too much, could it be less? like 50% or a little bit less? I've edited the [`xml layout`](https://paste.ofcode.org/7kMaYPB8943TdjFs99Bhk4)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Code changed to allow for initial placement in center of screen. See the `removeRule()` statements in `onTouch()`. Added parameter to vary the percentage of the image that must be "out" before toast is shown. See `isOut()`.

Comment: I know `removeRule()` but I'm using min15 not min17, but well.. I guess putting this : `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"` will work, so thanks... seems like it's working perfect, I'll depure it asap :D Thanks bro

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I changed the code to accommodate <API 17. "wrap_content" may also work but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Means that API 15 will center it as well? What do you think it's better to put it on wrap_content or d the comprobation that you did?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS The code will work with API 15 as well as API 17+. I updated the XML to reflect `wrap_content` like your updated XML and the centering of the image.

Comment: One question why I can not set the image to the center? If I put the image to the center of the screen it won't drag...

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS How are you centering the image? Is it with `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertical` or another way such as `layout_centerInParent`? If "center in parent", you will need to add the code `lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);`.

Comment: Ah I didn't remember to uncomment the if stuff (build sdk) now is working, thanks, but it means that if one versions of android it won't be centered?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS It will be centered for all versions of Android if you use the code in the answer.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to listen touch events on the view instead of the activity?

Answer (score 3):

The framework has a class called [`View.OnDragListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html). See the [Drag & Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) tutorial.

See also additionally the [`DraggablePanel`](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) project if you want to study how this can be done.

Comment: I've tried the last example, but how can I determine when the view is going to "leave" the device? Also I have this on a ConstraintLayout it will affect on this? I'm trying this [example](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-drag-a-view-in-android) do you think it's ok? Also how do I detect if it's going out of the device? I thought to compare X and Y with windowheight and windowwidth

Comment: I've edited my question with my current code, could you help me out of what I'm asking?

Comment: have you studied my case?

Comment: Yes Y.S. I did it, for sure, but when I try the example it doesn't move here's the sample [code](https://paste.ofcode.org/BFenDHif5ZfRVv6mPpMkzg)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS: Sorry for the delay, friend. Will look at it at the soonest.

Comment: Okay thanks master, hope I can get a correct way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this method to drag an ImageView , I hope that this can help you : 
So I defined those attributes of the class :

```
 private float xCoOrdinate, yCoOrdinate;
 private double screenCenterX, screenCenterY;
```

Then I implement this code under the OnCreate() method of the activity  :

```
 mRrootLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(255);

    /**
     * Calculate max hypo value and center of screen.
     */
    final DisplayMetrics display = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    screenCenterX = display.widthPixels / 2;
    screenCenterY = (display.heightPixels - getStatusBarHeight()) / 2;
    final double maxHypo = Math.hypot(screenCenterX, screenCenterY);

    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            /**
             * Calculate hypo value of current imageview position according to center
             */
            double centerYPos = mImageView.getY() + (mImageView.getHeight() / 2);
            double centerXPos = mImageView.getX() + (mImageView.getWidth() / 2);
            double a = screenCenterX - centerXPos;
            double b = screenCenterY - centerYPos;
            double hypo = Math.hypot(a, b);

            /**
             * change alpha of background of layout
             */
            alpha = (int) (hypo * 255) / (int) maxHypo;
            if (alpha < 255)
                mRrootLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(255 - alpha);

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    xCoOrdinate = mImageView.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    yCoOrdinate = mImageView.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mImageView.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     if (alpha > 50) {
                        Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this, "Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this, "In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.animate().x(0).y((float) screenCenterY - mImageView.getHeight() / 2).setDuration(100).start();
                        mRrootLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                    }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nmm could you put a simple toast instead of animate it? I mean if you are going to get out of the device a toast (when the image is arround 50% out of the screen)?

Comment: I added for you the toasts sis . Try it and if you have question don't hesitate to ask me

Comment: PS: The Toasts will be shown when you invoke ACTION_UP and it will display "Out" if you are 50% out of the screen and "in" if you still in 50% of the screen

Comment: Well the 50% of the image was a random number, but yes, this night I'll make a test and I'll let you know, but it can not be caught on action_move?

Comment: I've tested it and seems like it does not work, as a [`getStatusBarHeight()` method I got this from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28965901/4385913), it's okay? It does say OUT if I'm on the middle of the screen

Answer (score 3):

A working example of how to move all the views contained in a RelativeLayout using onTouch. Hope it will help :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private RelativeLayout mRelLay;
    private float mInitialX, mInitialY;
    private int mInitialLeft, mInitialTop;
    private View mMovingView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRelLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < mRelLay.getChildCount(); i++)
            mRelLay.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mMovingView = view;
                mLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mMovingView.getLayoutParams();
                mInitialX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                mInitialY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                mInitialLeft = mLayoutParams.leftMargin;
                mInitialTop = mLayoutParams.topMargin;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mMovingView != null) {
                    mLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mMovingView.getLayoutParams();
                    mLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (mInitialLeft + motionEvent.getRawX() - mInitialX);
                    mLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) (mInitialTop + motionEvent.getRawY() - mInitialY);
                    mMovingView.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mMovingView = null;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like it's working but looks like on the left it's not detecting it, right? I'd like to get a toast or something when user tries to move the image out of the device TOP/DOWN/RIGHT/LEFT you got me?

Comment: Then you should limit movement adding in ACTION_MOVE something like if(topMargin < 0) topMargin = 0;     and     if(topMargin + height > windowheight)  topMargin = windowheight - height;  and the same for left margin and width.

Comment: Could you make a sample of that so I can test and I can approve it?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Add right/bottom margin in step 3 to prevent image zoomed.
You can see if you not change right/bottom margin, image will zoomed by relative layout.
[image: preview solution old and new]

1. getMeasuredHeight/Width avoid `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT`.
2. If there is a toolbar/actionbar then `topMargin + height > relativeLayout's height` also applies to out of bottom determination.
3. record state of `out of bound` avoid toast continuous appear.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

       Point lastPoint = new Point();
       RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

       boolean lastOutOfTop = false;
       boolean lastOutOfLeft = false;
       boolean lastOutOfRight = false;
       boolean lastOutOfBottom = false;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           (findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setOnTouchListener(this);
           relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
           //1. user's finger
           final Point point = new Point((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());

           switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   // 2. record the last touch point
                   lastPoint = point;
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   // 3. get the move offset
                   final Point offset = new Point(point.x-lastPoint.x, point.y-lastPoint.y);
                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                           .getLayoutParams();
                   layoutParams.leftMargin += offset.x;
                   layoutParams.topMargin += offset.y;
                   // * also check right/bottom Margin
                   layoutParams.rightMargin = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth() - layoutParams.leftMargin+view.getMeasuredWidth();
                   layoutParams.bottomMargin = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight() - layoutParams.topMargin+view.getMeasuredHeight();
                   view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                   // 4. record the last touch point
                   lastPoint = point;
                   break;
           }

           // 5. check bounds
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
           boolean outOfTop = layoutParams.topMargin < 0;
           boolean outOfLeft = layoutParams.leftMargin < 0;
           boolean outOfBottom = layoutParams.topMargin+view.getMeasuredHeight() > relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
           boolean outOfRight = layoutParams.leftMargin+view.getMeasuredWidth() > relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();

           // 6. if out of bound
           if (outOfLeft&&!lastOutOfLeft) Toast.makeText(this, "OUT Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if (outOfTop&&!lastOutOfTop) Toast.makeText(this, "OUT Top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if (outOfBottom&&lastOutOfBottom) Toast.makeText(this, "OUT Bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if (outOfRight&&lastOutOfRight)  Toast.makeText(this, "OUT Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           // 7. record
           lastOutOfTop = outOfTop;
           lastOutOfLeft = outOfLeft;
           lastOutOfBottom = outOfBottom;
           lastOutOfRight = outOfRight;
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I said Toast to let me know when I'm going out of the screen

Comment: Yes toast prompted beyond the border.
My example is only one time when the border is exceeded

Comment: I'll test int in about 1h and I'll let you know ^^

Comment: I've tested it and I don't understand why if I drag it to the right it zooms out, I've tried it with another image (more little) and seems like it works, but when I put my real image, it zooms in/out whenever I try to move the image. Maybe because it's too big?

Comment: Yes if we don't change left/bottom margin, then image will zooms in/out. I've update my answer with a preview of the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via this code.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int windowWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
int windowHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Now in your onTouch method, calculate if the target location exceeds the above dimensions.

if( currentXLocation + deltaX > windowWidth ){

```
// this will ensure that target location 
// is always <= windowHeight
deltaX = windowWidth - currentXLocation; 

} else if( currentXLocation + deltaX < 0){

deltaX = -(currentXLocation);

} else if (...){

// perform similar calculations for the rest 

}
```

Comment: Copy the same answer is not useful, so please if you put an answer and you don't want to being downvoted, test it on a sample project and post your real code.

Comment: Bro, this is the code that solved my problem, if you want a sample let me know, ill make you one :)

Comment: It's easier to me to test it, yes.